# In RxSwift how can I set up a Subject to observe another Observable?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Let's say I have the following:

```
let theSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
let theObservable = Observable.just("Hello?")
```

How do I set the `theSubject` to observer `theObservable`?

> In RxSwift we say that a subject is an observer and can subscribe
>   to one or more Observables...

Can you show a simple code example of how I can connect `theSubject` as an observer of `theObservable` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The answer is

```
theObservable
    .subscribe(onNext: { theSubject.onNext($0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This will make sure that every time that the `theObservable` emits, the value will be passed to `theSubject` too.

**Note**
This only passes the value `onNext`, if you want to handle all the cases, then use `bind(to:)` as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51996246/2664437) by Daniel T. (or `drive` for `Driver`s)

### Example with more Observables

In the following example values from different `Observables` will be passed to `theSubject`

```
let theSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
let theObservable = Observable.just("Hello?")
let anotherObservable = Observable.just("Hey there")

theSubject.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

theObservable
    .subscribe(onNext: { theSubject.onNext($0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

anotherObservable
    .subscribe(onNext: { theSubject.onNext($0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

### Output

[image: The subject]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!  Thanks for your careful explanation EridB!

Answer (score 15):

The code is:

```
theObservable
    .bind(to: theSubject)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

or:

```
theObservable 
    .subscribe(theSubject)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

If you only do `subscribe(onNext:)` as others have suggested, only the onNext events will get passed along. You should use bind to pass everything along.

(But really you probably shouldn't use a subject. Instead bind the thing(s) that are listening to the subject to the Observable directly.

Comment: You need `RxCocoa` for `bind`

Comment: True, you could just use `.subscribe(theSubject)` instead of `.bind(to: theSubject)`.

Comment: Is there anyway to tie the cancellation / disposing to the subject?  I am having to jump through these hoops because I can' create the (inner) observable until a first step completes inside a function, but need to create and return the outer subject for the function's caller to wait on.  Ideally the caller could short circuit the second stage just be releasing the the subject, so there would be no audience for the inner observable.  (Thanks!)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking above. Maybe post a new question with more detail?